# webサーバでソースが開かれず、エラーのような画面が開かれる。

Tags: nginx

nginxとphp-fpmを用いたweb環境を作っているのですが、
手順か何かを間違えて、webを開こうとするとnginxエラーが出ていました。

nginxとphp-fpmの環境設定を見直して、自動起動設定、再起動は行いました。
ですが以下のエラーが出てしまいます。

色々やっても変わらないので直すためのアイデアが思い浮かびません。
経験ある方、教えていただけますと幸いです

```
An error occurred.
Sorry, the page you are looking for is currently unavailable.
Please try again later.
If you are the system administrator of this resource then you should check the error log for details.
Faithfully yours, nginx.
```

Comment: エラーメッセージにあるように、error logをチェックするのが良いです。

Comment: どのような手順を行ったのかも、どのようなリカバリを試したのか記述するとより良いでしょう。

Comment: 例えば設定ファイルをデフォルトから書き換えたのであれば、その内容も質問文に含めてください。同様にどのような手順を行ったのかも含まれていると回答のヒントになるでしょう。  / ヘルプの [再現可能なサンプルコードの書き方](https://ja.stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) も参考にしてください。

Comment: 細かな指摘になりますが、「ソースが開かれず」だと「ソースコードがそのまま画面に表示される」といった印象です。実際には「プログラムが実行されず」ではないでしょうか？

Answer (score -1):

solved the problem.

It was the cause of the error. php-fpm unix domain socket.

Comment: 解決方法を日本語で記述することで、後からの視認性がさらに向上すると思います。